# pyenv does not affect the python being used and activate does not exist

Tags: python, pyenv

I am using a `pyenv` guide from here [Managing Multiple Python Versions With pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)

I have already created a 3.6.7 version:

```
13:24:51/hercl $pyenv versions
  system
* 3.6.7 (set by /Users/steve/.pyenv/version)
```

I made 3.6.7 global:

```
pyenv global 3.6.7
```

But the python being used is the system version

```
 $python -V
Python 3.9.9
```

Also there are many references to `pyenv activate` but that command does not exist??

```
 $pyenv commands
--version
commands
completions
exec
global
help
hooks
init
install
local
prefix
rehash
root
shell
shims
uninstall
version
version-file
version-file-read
version-file-write
version-name
version-origin
versions
whence
which
```

So how is the 3.6.7 version to be activated?

**Update**. here is how I installed and enabled `pyenv`:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Also do I *really* need to uninstall the python versions already installed via `brew`?  [installing-pyenv-on-macos](https://binx.io/blog/2019/04/12/installing-pyenv-on-macos/)

Comment: How did you install `pyenv`? Have you enabled it in your shell?

Comment: @Chris  I updated the OP with that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I had installed `pyenv` I had missed installing `pyenv-virtualenv`.

```
brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

The following had already been added to `~/.bashrc` but the second line had not been working. it does now

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

And `pyenv activate` now runs fine

```
$pyenv activate 3.6.7
pyenv-virtualenv: virtualenv `/Users/steve/git/hercl/.venv' is already activated
```

Wow that was a confusing problem.

**Update** An additional step is needed: to manually add the `$HOME/.pyenv/shims` directory to the PATH.  So now the last three lines of my `~/.bash_profile` are:

```
export PATH=.:$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$HOME/.pyenv/shims:/opt/brew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```